# Material UI: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'array')

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am writing unit tests for the component I am working on. I used autocomplete from Material UI, but my unit test failed with the error message 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'array').' I've tried to fix this issue but have been unsuccessful. Could someone please help me resolve this issue? I want to run a simple unit test just to check that my component renders correctly

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Autocomplete, Box } from "@mui/material";
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { SelectDropdownType } from 'types';

const SelectDropdown: React.FC<SelectDropdownType> = ({
    options,
    handleChange,
    control,
    placeholder,
    value
}) => {
    return (
        <Box data-testid="custom-dropdown">
            <Controller
                control={control}
                name="clientDetails"
                render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => {
                    const hasTripNumberError = error && 'tripNumber' in error;
                    const { ref } = field;

                    return (
                        <Autocomplete
                            options={options?.length > 0 ? options : []}

                            placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : 'Select option'}
                            value={value ? value : ''}
                            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                                handleChange(newValue)
                            }}
                            renderInput={(params) => (
                                <TextField
                                    {...params}
                                    className="mt-[0px]"
                                    size="small"
                                    error={hasTripNumberError}
                                    helperText={hasTripNumberError ? 'Field is required' : ''}
                                    margin="normal"
                                    label="Trip Number"
                                    inputRef={ref}
                                    variant="outlined"
                                />
                            )}
                        />
                    );
                }}
            />
        </Box>

    );
};

export default SelectDropdown;
```

**Unit Test using Jest**

```
import { enhancedRender, screen } from '../../../helpers/Testing/TestingUtils';
import SelectDropdown from "../../../common/SelectDropdown";

const TestUnit = (props: any) => {
    return enhancedRender(<SelectDropdown {...props} />);
};

// It should render the correctly

describe("CustomDropdown", () => {
    // It should show the dropdown with default
    it("should render correctly", () => {
        const { container } = TestUnit({ options: [], control: {}, handlechange: jest.fn(), placeholder: 'Select Option' });
        expect(container).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

});
```

Comment: There's no reference to `array` in the code provided; we can't see where it's attempting to read `array`.